# Ubuntu One Windows crashs when opening preferences

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows, preferences

Ubuntu One on Windows keeps on crashing every time I try to open the preferences window. I tried re-installing many times and still crashes. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report since Ubuntu One for Windows is in beta, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).